# I thought "NlogN" is "N" times "logN", but why is it described as "double PLUS an amount proportional to N"

Tags: algorithm, collections

I'm currently learning about the big O notation. In the material, `O(NlogN)` was described as `Doubled plus an amount proportional to N`. But I thought that would be `O(N + logN)` and not `O(NlogN)` (I thought `O(NlogN)` is `Double times logN`).

Is there something logically wrong with my understanding?

[image]

Comment: Did you see "Effect on the running time if N is doubled"? if "N is doubled..." then O(2*N*log(2*N)) = O(2Nlog2 + 2NlogN) = double of O(NlogN) + O(kN) where k = 2log2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `N` with `2N` as stated:

`2N log 2N = 2N * (log N + log 2)` (using logarithm rules)

- Doubled original term `2 * (N log N)`
- Additional term `(2 log 2) * N` i.e. "proportional to `N`".